# let 束縛の括弧を忘れてつい (let (x 1) e) と書いてしまいます。静的なチェッカはありませんか？

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

たまに Emacs Lisp を書くのですが、一つだけの束縛を持つ `let` 式で、

```
(let ((x 1)) x)
```

と書くべきところをつい

```
(let (x 1) x)
```

と書いてしまい、実行時エラーで苦しんでいます。もちろんデバッガを使えばわかることなのですが、実際にコードを走らせて見る前にこのような間違いを見つける方法はないでしょうか。たとえば、このような怪しい束縛はハイライトしてくれるととても助かります。( `(let (x) x)` で `x` が `nil` になることは理解しています… )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`elint`の他にバイトコンパイルする手段があります.

```
(let (x 1) x)
```

というファイルをバイトコンパイルすると, 以下のようにエラーが出ます.

```
Compiling file /home/syohei/junk/elisp/test2.el at Tue Dec 16 15:41:42 2014
test2.el:1:1:Error: Wrong type argument: listp, 1
```

また `lexical-bindings`を有効にすると

```
;;; some-package.el --- This is some package. -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(let (x y) x)
```

のような内容でも警告されます(未使用変数という形になってしまいますが).

```
Compiling file /home/syohei/junk/elisp/test.el at Tue Dec 16 15:43:19 2014
test.el:3:1:Warning: Unused lexical variable `y'
```

バイトコンパイルは diredで **B**をタイプすると行えます.
(依存関係をチェックする際などは, `emacs -Q`で起動してバイトコンパイルすると望ましいです)

`lexical-bindings`は Emacs 24から利用できます. これからリリースするような
パッケージは Emacs23をサポートする必要はないと思いますので, 常に有効にしておいて
よいと思います(クロージャも書きやすくなりますし).

バイトコンパイルはその他 deprecated, obsoletedな変数, 関数等の指摘も行って
くれるので, パッケージをリリースする際は必ず行うことが望ましいと考えています.

参考

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LexicalBinding

Answer (score 4):

Emacs に標準で `elint.el` が同梱されています。

今ポイントしている関数には `elint-defun` を使うことができます。
他にも、 `elint-current-buffer`, `elint-file` や `elint-directory` があります。

例えば以下のようなバッファで `elint-current-buffer` すると、 `*Elint*` バッファに結果が示されます。

```
(let (x 1) x)

(defun my-test ()
  (let (x '(1 2 3)) x))
```

結果は、

```
Linting /tmp/test.el

In top level expression:
test.el:1:Error: Malformed `let' declaration: 1

In function my-test:
test.el:3:Warning: Suspect varlist: (let (x (quote (1 2 3))) x)

Linting finished.
```

Comment: (let (x 1) e) については elint が教えてくれました！ (let (x y) x) については無理みたいでした。まあこれも真正な Lisp の文なのでしかたないのかもしれませんね。それでもだいぶ助かります！ありがとうございました。

Comment: 確かに、(let (x y) x) 等もう少し頑張って欲しいなあと思う所もありますね。比較的小さなプログラムならば、実行時エラーを出してもそのまま修正しながらやっつけることができる気もしますけれども、規模が大きくなってくると…という気がしています。

Answer (score 1):

`let`の方がfunctionではなくて "special form" です。

必要な関数の引数は [(def list), (begin exps)]:

```
(define (z x)
 (let ((q 1)
       (y 2))
     (do-stuff x q y))
```

これで (def list) の長さは2: `((q 1) (y 2))`

長さは1だけでも `((q 1))` を書かないと意味が違いますね。 〔 `((q 1))` VS `(q 1)` 〕

emacs lispでは`(let (x) x)` の意味は `(define x ())` -> `nil`

Comment: よくある間違いをプログラムを動かすことなくチェックしたいという質問なのですが… I am not asking the right syntax or meaning of let binding, but a static way to detect typical misusages of it, probably a kind of "lint". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

静的なチェッカーでは無いのですが、
macroで新しい構文を作ってしまえば、良いのではないですかね?

```
(defmacro elet (binds &rest body)
  (let ((new-binds (make-new-binds binds)))
    `(let ,new-binds ,@body)))

(defun make-new-binds (binds)
  (if (null binds)
      nil
    (let ((var (car binds))
          (init-form (cadr binds)))
      (cons `(,var ,init-form) (make-new-binds (cddr binds))))))
```

とすれば、

```
(elet (x (+ 1 2) y (+ 1 2 (- 3 4))) (+ x y)) 
;;  => -5
```

となります。

これで、楽に掛けますね!